# how to make table with only border line and vertical line html

Tags: html, css

I need make to this table look like in image the blue lines in the table are what i need how to make it please help me thanks in advance
[image]

```html
<style>

td, th {  
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
table{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
 
 
</table>
```

Comment: Try `border-collapse: collapse` and set a border to the table cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Insert This codes:***

```
td:not(:last-child),th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
  //more code
}
```

```css
td, th {  
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

td:not(:last-child),th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: it comes to table with multiple rows it is the perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

Add `border-collapse:collapse` in table, this collapsed the border of table into `single border` and then you can add `border-right` to td, th tag.

```css
td, th {  
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
th:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(1){
    border-right:1px solid blue; /*Add this*/
}
th:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2){
    border-right:1px solid blue; /*Add this*/
}
table{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-collapse:collapse;/*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
 
 
</table>
```

Comment: may i know what border collapse is doing here is it overwriting the td th border

Comment: Just a suggestion, maybe making it so that there are only the lines on the sides of **Contact**. I think thats what is wanted, based on the first image provided in the question

Comment: sorry i only want  blue border inside the table not in left or right border of table please help me in that

Comment: @Sumanr https://jsfiddle.net/b2wxmn6f/ Check this jsFiddle you will find that all border are separated and visible as boxes i.e. there some default values for each tags, here table has default value of border-collapse as separate as shown in fiddle, to align them in one line we use border-collapse:collapse. I have edited my solution please check.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @frnt  now i am clear with that but please help me to make only inside of table have blue line not border line

Comment: yeah i checked but i want the exact one as in above image i added

Comment: @Sumanr please check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b2wxmn6f/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/b2wxmn6f/2/ they are exact like above image.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/b2wxmn6f/1 - this one helped me thanks for the answer its working